# Control the way elements load according to device (mobile/tablet,etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use Javascript/jQuery to control the way my elements load, meaning if I am on iPhone or Android mobile and for iPad and tablets. I dun wanna use CSS media queries, I need it in Javascript or jQuery. Any hints or links to read would be nice, thanks

Comment: **Why** don't you want to use media queries?

Answer (score 0):

You could detect device width and change settings / elements from there ?

```
var viewSize = $(window).width();

/* if is below 481px  then it might be a phone :) */
if (viewSize < 481) {
  //something special
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I used screen.width and it worked fine. Just make sure that your script is right before the end of the page to guarantee that all elements are loaded. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
if ((screen.width>720)) {
document.getElementById("photos").style.marginLeft="110px";
document.getElementById("videos").style.marginRight="100px";
}
});
</script>
```